# Many nested for loops

Tags: c#, for-loop

This issue was faced while coding C#, but i assume the answer is applicable in any programming language.

i need multiple nested loops (let's say 9, but can be 100). My code should execute like:

```
for (a1=0;a1<N;a1++)
for (a2=0;a2<N;a2++)
...
for (a9=0;a9<N;a9++)
   //do something
```

I think that this code could be shorter by using a variable `M=9` and an int array `a[]` instead of a1,a2,a3,...

Could you provide any hints?

**Edit:**
I know i don't need to use nested loops to do this. I am just asking if I can do this using a variable `M=9` an int array `a[]` and less code.

If you really need to see something complicated, i wrote the following code:

```
        string[] s1 = new string[3]{ "apples", "oranges","bananas" };
        string[] s2 = new string[5] { "are", "are not", "should be", "must be","seem to be" };
        string[] s3 = new string[3] { "big", "small", "tasty" };

        int[] a=new int[10];
        int[] step = new int[10];
        step[1] = 1; step[2] = 1; step[3] = 2;
        for (a[1] = 0; a[1] < s1.Length; a[1]+=step[1])
            for (a[2] = 0; a[2] < s2.Length; a[2]+=step[2])
                for (a[3] = 0; a[3] < s3.Length; a[3]+=step[3])
                    Console.WriteLine(s1[a[1]] + " " + s2[a[2]] + " " + s3[a[3]]);
```

imagine this with more arrays: s4,s5,...s10. (this could be an array of arrays `s[]`, or a 2-dimensional array `s[,]`.

Comment: You need `100` `for loop`s. Are you sure? That sounds like one hell of an X,Y problem to me. Explain what you're trying to do.

Comment: Sounds like a problem for recursion but you'd have to be more specific with your problem.  You gave us your solution but not your problem.  We might have a different solution entirely.

Comment: Do you need to do something 9 times or do you need 9 loops?

Comment: Explain the problem,probably it can be done in a easier way.

Comment: It doesn't have to be a practical problem. it's just a question. if you need something applicable could be: write all 100-digit numbers with digits containing only {0,1,2,3,4} (i.e. base 5). I know the specific problem can be solved otherwise, but it's just an example

Comment: You don't need nested loops to do that

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The limits array defines the upper bound of each component ( -1, equivalent to < N in a for loop). The components array holds the values for each component.

```
int[] limits = { 9, 20, 15, 30, 8, 40, 10 };
int[] components = new int[limits.Length];

bool done = false;
while (!done)
{
    //do work here using the components
    int M = components[0];
    int N = components[1];
    int O = components[2];
    int P = components[3];
    //etc
    //first iteration M=0,N=0,O=0, etc

    //this part does the incrementing for the next iteration
    for (int j = 0; j < limits.Length; j++)
    {
        components[j]++;
        if (components[j] < limits[j])
            break;
        components[j] = 0;
        if (j == limits.Length - 1)
            done = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! That's what i was looking for. Is it something that is being used frequently? I mean, was it something i could find in some tutorials or examples, or did you just code it now?

Comment: i coded it now, but from memory i had to do this in the past once. its very unusual as you can see from people's reactions to the question...

Answer (score 0):

Your code

```
for (a1=0;a1<N;a1++)
for (a2=0;a2<N;a2++)
...
for (a9=0;a9<N;a9++)
```

can be replaced with this:

```
    int M = 9;
    int N = 20;
    int index = 0;


    for (int x = 0; x < M; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
        {
            // do something
            // perhaps a[index++] = some value;
        }
    }
```

There are better solutions for your problem but I think this is what you've asked for.

Comment: ok. now imagine M=9,N=20,O=15,P=20,Q=30 and all these nested.

Comment: This was not your original question. And why don't you simply sum up M, N, O .etc to one variable?

Comment: yes that was my original question. there are 9 nested loops, not 2. Nevertheless, if you now really understood what i want, could you provide a solution? (every variable represents something different in the "do something" part. i don't just need to do the same thing 9*20*15*20*30 times

Comment: I edited my post. My code is exactly doing what you requested with your code-sample. Of course you can change N within the M-loop. If you don't ask a concrete question it is difficult to give a concrete answer.